# HP DL165G7: NMI error

Tags: hardware, hp, ipmi

One of "my" DL165 G7 Proliants has rebooted out of the blue for the second time this month. The reboot was accompanied by these system event log entries in LightsOut:

```
Event Type  Date    Time    Source  Description Direction
OEM --  --  --  00 00 00 00 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  --
Generic 07/19/2013  16:40:38    NMI Detect  State Asserted  Assertion
Generic 07/19/2013  16:40:42    Gen ID 0x41 Run-time Stop   Assertion
OEM 07/19/2013  16:40:42    000137  01 80 00 00 00 01   --
OEM 07/19/2013  16:40:42    000137  02 54 44 4f 00 01   --
OEM 07/19/2013  16:40:42    000137  02 00 00 00 00 01   --
OEM 07/19/2013  16:40:42    000137  03 00 00 00 00 01   --
OEM 07/19/2013  16:40:42    000137  03 00 00 00 00 01   --
OEM 07/19/2013  16:40:42    000137  04 00 00 00 00 01   --
OEM 07/19/2013  16:40:42    000137  04 00 00 00 00 01   --
OEM 07/19/2013  16:40:42    000137  05 00 00 00 00 01   --
OEM 07/19/2013  16:40:42    000137  05 00 00 00 00 01   --
Generic 07/19/2013  16:43:54    Gen ID 0x41 C: boot completed   Assertion
OEM 07/19/2013  16:43:54    000137  00 b4 6c e9 51 00   --
```

I have contacted HP support to get help decoding the events, but unfortunately without any notable success - I have been told that there is no accessible documentation available. What is it trying to tell me and how do I find out what is broken here?

Edit: the system is running Hyper-V 2012. The only useful event concerning the reset is Kernel-Power/41 with a BugcheckCode of 128 / 0x00000080 and BugcheckParameter1 of 0x4f4454 which match the first two OEM lines of the iLO event log (after you swap the bytes in little-endian manner, at least). The bugcheck code led me to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559250%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which is bluntly stating that *"the exact cause is difficult to determine"*.

In the HP support center, I could find a [seemingly similar problem description](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/mostViewedDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=398225&spf_p.tpst=psiContentDisplay&spf_p.prp_psiContentDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-c01657288-1%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) with the solution being to synchronize the clocks between cluster nodes. While my breaking host indeed does run in a cluster, I have the clocks synchronized and I cannot reproduce the issue when the clocks are drifting apart (the obvious Kerberos authentication problems put aside, nothing much is happening if I desync the clocks).

The odd information I have been able to collect on the issue so far:

- A run-time stop entry in the IPMI event log indicates an OS blue screen ([chapter 2.5.2 of the Winbond/Nuvoton WPCM450 BMC user guide](http://img.jp.fujitsu.com/downloads/jp/jhpc/products/hx2560m1/ipmi-user-guide.pdf))
- The [IPMI documentation from the OpenIPMI project](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/bmc-device.8.html) man page states that *you cannot send OEM events using the standard interface*
- NMIs [seemed to be common in the past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-maskable_interrupt) to signal ECC parity errors and initiate resets of the PC, but the information seems antiquated and in both cases I would expect appropriate event log entries telling me that errors or resets have occured - which I do not have.
- According to the [bmc-device man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/bmc-device.8.html) and [this post from the vger Linux kernel mailing list](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/patch-2-6-ipmi-panic-generator-id-help-180357711.html), it seems like the generator ID of 0x41 means the NMI is triggered by the local management or the kernel.

Comment: Usually RAM or CPU. What OS are you running?

Comment: @ewwhite Hyper-V 2012. Do you have any information about what ECC two-bit errors look like in the system event log? Or if single-bit errors are logged? So far, I only ever have observed this in Fujitsu's event logs and can't tell.

Comment: The only way to generate a NMI on that platform is through the iLO interface (as far as I know). Have you tried updating iLO?

Comment: @ChrisS the iLO webif reports `Firmware Version: 4.25` which is the latest & greatest as far as I can see from the DL165 downloads page.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with HP ProLiant G380 G6 and Windows 2008 R2, digging into the support and help forums got me nowhere, I eventually used the HP Smart Update Manager DVD to install all the latest updates on the server, a year and a half passed with no errors so far.

It might be a long shot, but try to use the latest updates, [here's the latest HP SUM DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18964&prodSeriesId=1844067&prodNameId=1844068&swEnvOID=4064&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b)

If you try to run that on a 2012 server, you might get an error that is it not compatible, [according to HP that is is normal](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=4091396&prodTypeId=15351&objectID=c03517970) and you only need to ignore the error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've just used this ISO on a DL360p with Windows 2012 yesterday:
http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/service_packs/en/index.html
It also contains the SUM and I experienced no errors or warnings.